# China not showing on chloropleth map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am trying to make a simple chloropleth map in r. While I can create the map, China does not show up at all, leaving a giant hole in the map. I have checked that China is in the data, so I am not sure what is going on. here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)

## load data ----
data(country.map, package = "choroplethrMaps")
co2 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/acircleda/tmp/master/food emissions.csv") %>% 
  mutate(region = tolower(country))

data<-co2 %>% 
  left_join(country.map, by="region") %>%
  group_by(region) %>% mutate(
    c02sum = sum(co2_emmission)
  )

ggplot(data, aes(long, lat, group = group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = c02sum), color = "white", na="grey80")+
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "C")

##no china

china<-data %>% filter(region == "china") ##china is in the data
```

[image: nochina]

Comment: China shows up for me in both the dataframe and on the plotted map. So at least your code is working here.

Comment: can you change `na="grey80"` to a different color? The outline of China is showing up but might be missing data for c02?

Comment: also where you create c02sum try `c02sum = sum(co2_emmission,na.rm=TRUE)`, I don't know the data but this is where I would start

Comment: I added `na.rm=T`, removed the na="grey80", and still no changes. There is def. data for China. It should be in the blues based on the values.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot open your csv file... Have you tried your code in a totally empty session? Have you filtered your data somewhere using `filter`, for example by subregion? This can remove large parts of data because it silently removes NAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by first, summarise, and then join. I'd also do a full join just to see if there are any countries in the map that are not in your co2 data and if there are any countries in your co2 data that are not in the map (they'll be shown as grey). A right join should give the same reuslts, but a left join will cause these missing countries to appear missing altogether, which will look weird.

```
data <- co2 %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% summarise(   # do this first
    c02sum = sum(co2_emmission, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  full_join(country.map, by="region")

ggplot(data, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = c02sum), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'grey', name = expression(CO[2]~emission~(tonnes))) +
  ggtitle(expression(Global~CO[2]~emissions~by~country)) +
  theme_void()
```

[image: Global CO2 emissions by country]

The countries in the map that are missing from the co2 data (there are 50) are:

```
data %>%
   filter(is.na(c02sum)) %>%
   distinct(region) %>% 
   arrange(region)
# A tibble: 50 x 1
   region                  
   <chr>                   
 1 afghanistan             
 2 antarctica              
 3 azerbaijan              
 4 benin                   
 5 bhutan                  
 6 brunei                  
 7 burkina faso            
 8 burundi                 
 9 central african republic
10 chad                    
# … with 40 more rows
```

And the countries in your co2 data that are not in the map (there are 8) are:

```
data %>%
   filter(is.na(long)) %>%
   distinct(region)
# A tibble: 8 x 1
  region          
  <chr>           
1 barbados        
2 bermuda         
3 french polynesia
4 grenada         
5 maldives        
6 malta           
7 mauritius       
8 new caledonia
```

You could also determine this using `setdiff`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But the resulting data set is very large (95K) compared to only 10K (the same as the country.map) using `summarise`. And the plotting takes 3 seconds longer. Imagine doing this for a much larger data frame. You only need the summaries.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your data join. What you actually want, is a `right_join`. NAs can be coloured in your `scale_fill` functions with `na.value =` .

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)

## load data ----
data(country.map, package = "choroplethrMaps")
co2 <- read_csv('your.csv')%>% 
  mutate(region = tolower(country))
                               
data <- co2 %>% 
  right_join(country.map, by="region") %>% #critical
  group_by(region) 

ggplot(data, aes(long, lat, group = group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = co2_emmission), na.rm ="grey80") +
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'grey')
```

[image]